# Add New Version with New Source code by Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

Scenario,
ABC app on App store with version 1.0
Now i wants to update it with version 1.1

But actual problem is Old source code (Almost 2 years old) has weird behavior, So many things are mess up. Now i am going to create New Project with same feature, same name, same interface, same images etc.

Will apple accept my next version 1.1 from new source code files ?

Please help me elaborate words.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes they will accept, you just need to take care of `APPID`, and `AppName`, they can't be different, you can always add a new version for old app, and upload new version, a new version can use new source code too, but yes it should not change the app behaviour, I mean features..

Comment: This will be accepted. Make sure you explain the changes what you have made for differentiating v1.0 vs v1.1. Also check the bundleID. This should be same as far iPhonic said appid & app name should also be taken care

Comment: May I recommend since it is such a big change that instead of version 1.1 you go for version 2.0. Normally there is a convention for software versioning, such as you may have 1.2.3 version out and you need to do a small text change so on new release it would go to 1.2.4, but then you need to do a bug fix so you would then change the middle one to 1.3.0 then any major changes would be the first one so in your case you would change to 2.0 or 2.0.0 have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning Not really related to your question just some advice.

Comment: Good one, Popeye .. Nice guide line, +1..

Answer (score 2):

Applications in xCode are identified by its name, the BundleIdentifier, Version and Build.

You can of course create the new project and update the code and put it in the store AS LONG AS the information above is absolutely equal and the compiled appilcation is signed with the same certificate information.

This is exactly the case for example when you had to reinstall your machine and recreate the workspace locally.

---

**EDIT:** Of couse you have to increase the build string to your new version to make the update succeed. My bad in the first place! :D

Comment: Increase the build string means ? please

Comment: Ah ... I've mistaken that you write 1.1 in the version string, not the build string. So just set the Version to 1.1 and if you don't use "Build" ignore it.